# SlidesJS slider is slow and jumpy on iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, slider

I have a website with a slider. The slider contains some pictures as well as hidden videos. When certain "holdframes" are clicked, the picture is hidden and then the video begins to play.

This works fine on a computer, and in all browsers. But as soon as I try it on iOS, the transition animations get really slow and sometimes don't happen at all. Often times on the iPad there is not transition at all. Just a second of black space then the new slide.

I rebuilt the slider on a testing server with JUST the slider. It is the exact same one that is on my site, but it's the only thing on the page. When I view this from iOS, it works great! The transitions are smooth and just how I intended them.

So this leads me to believe that there might be something else on my original website that is interfering with the transitions, but only on iOS...

You can view the site here.
http://optidesign.squarespace.com/projects/motorola-sf700.html

If anyone can go ahead and take a look at try and give me some insight, that would be great. Otherwise my idea is to slowly rebuild the site on my testing server and check to see where it breaks. Or try different sliders, but Slidesjs worked the best for me.

Thanks

EDIT: I just noticed another little interesting bit. If you hit the "holdframe" and show the video instead, the transition from that slide to the next is smooth! But going back is still broken, and the rest of the slides stay broken...

Edit: Nobody has any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that the more elements in the DOM, the slower javascript will be to manipulate the DOM particularly when physically translating/moving elements. This would explain why the slider works well by itself but stumbles in situ.

I would highly recommend using CSS transitions to achieve the desired affect. Check out this tool: http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/

CSS `transition` in combination with `transform3d` allows the "sliding" of elements to be hardware accelerated on iOS and very smooth.